# How to draw connecting lines between web elements on a page

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, svg

I want to find the simplest ***barebones*** (that is, no libraries if possible; this is a learning exercise) way to draw a simple line between components.  [The elements are divs representing cards always stacked vertically](https://github.com/rossdrew/journal) potentially forever. Cards can be different heights.  The line will exit the left hand side of any given element (card a), turn 90 degrees and go up, turning 90 degrees back into another (card b).

[image: Example]

I've tried a few things.  I haven't got any fully working yet and they're looking like they all need some serious time dedicated to figuring them out.  What I want to know is what's the right/preferred way to do this so that I spend time on the right thing and it's future proof with the view:

1. I can add as many connecting lines as I need between any two boxes, not just consecutive ones
2. These lines obey resizing and scrolling down and up the cards
3. Some cards may not have an end point and will instead terminate top left of page, waiting for their card to scroll into view or be created.

### Attempts

My first thought was a ***<canvas>*** in a full column component on the left but aligning canvas' and the drawings in them to my divs was a pain, as well as having an infinite scrolling canvas.  Couldn't make it work.

Next I tried ***<div>s***.  Like [McBrackets](https://github.com/McInkay/McBrackets) has done [here](https://github.com/McInkay/McBrackets/blob/main/src/components/Match.js). Colouring the top, bottom and outer edge of the div and aligning it with the two cards in question but while I can position it relative to card a, I can't figure out how to then stop it at card b.

Lastly I tried ***<SVG>s***.  Just `.getElementById()` then add an SVG path that follows the instructions above. i.e.

```
    const connectingPath =
        "M " + aRect.left + " " + aRect.top + " " +
        "H " + (aRect.left - 50) +
        "V " + (bRect.top) +
        "H " + (bRect.left);
```

Nothing seems to line up, it's proving pretty difficult to debug and it's looking like a much more complex solution as I need to take into account resizing and whatnot.

Comment: @IPSDSILVA by between I don't mean separating.  I mean connecting (I'll rephrase the title). Line starts at div a and navigates to div b, connecting them.  hr is just a horizonal line.

Comment: Not sure if I understand everything correctly, but how about adding a (pseudo) Element to each of your connected boxes which takes care of drawing the part of the connection line that's part of the vertical space of the box it belongs to? So in your example you would have one element with a top and left border which starts in the middle of box "B" and ends at the middle of the margin between box "B" and "A". Then you'd have another element with a bottom and left border which starts at the middle of box "A" and also ends at the middle of the margin between boxes "A" and "B".

Comment: @Moritur would that work in the case where I wanted to connect A-C?

Comment: What do you expect to see when two connectors overlap?

Comment: @isherwood Once I figure out the basic connecting I'll also want connecters outer line to be further out depending on how many lines are live and how old each are.  So they all show vertically alongside.  They'll still crossover/combine when entering cards though.

Comment: SVG is the right solution here... just need to get everything lined up now.

Comment: @Brad it felt like the right solution.  Very simple, until everything started going a bit wobbly and I wondering if I was going down another crazy path.  Hence this question.

Comment: the simplest barebones way to do it: use one svg element with a viewBox="0 0 100 100" and preserveAspectRatio ="none" The svg element get stretched to the size of the container and uses the values for the items positions (percents) to draw the connectors. To avoid deformation use vector-effect: non-scaling-stroke; for the paths. Please take a look at this example: https://codepen.io/giaco/pen/xeWLvM

Comment: One last observation regarding the answer I provided. If these cards are dynamically loading in and out of the DOM, there will just be a little more work in the `scroll` event to check all connectors if either part of the connector is visible. If any part is visible, then render it using `addConnector`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be able to apply something like this by taking a few measurements from the boxes you want to connect; `offsetTop` and `clientHeight`.

---

**Update** Added some logic for undrawn cards requirement.

While this doesn't fully simulate dynamic populating of cards, I made an update to show how to handle a scenario where only one card is drawn.

1. Click connect using the default values (1 and 5). This will show an open connector starting from box 1.
2. Click "Add box 5". This will add the missing box and update the connector.

The remaining work here is to create an event listener on `scroll` to check the list of connectors. From there you can check if both boxes appear or not in the DOM (see `checkConnectors` function). If they appear, then pass values to `addConnector` which will connect them fully.

```js
class Container {
  constructor(element) {
    this.connectors = new Map();
    this.element = element;
  }

  addConnector(topBox, bottomBox, displayHalf = false) {
    if (!topBox && !bottomBox) throw new Error("Invalid params");
    const connector = new Connector(topBox, bottomBox, displayHalf);
    const connectorId = `${topBox.id}:${bottomBox.id}`;
    this.element.appendChild(connector.element);
    if (this.connectors.has(connectorId)) {
      connector.element.style.borderColor = this.connectors.get(connectorId).element.style.borderColor;
    } else {
      connector.element.style.borderColor = "#" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
    }
    this.connectors.set(connectorId, connector);
  }

  checkConnectors() {
    this.connectors.forEach((connector) => {
      if (connector.displayHalf) {
        connector.firstBox.updateElement();
        connector.secondBox.updateElement();

        if (connector.firstBox.element && connector.secondBox.element) {
          this.addConnector(connector.firstBox, connector.secondBox);
        }
      }
    });
  }
}

class Box {
  constructor(id) {
    this.id = id;
    this.updateElement();
  }

  getMidpoint() {
    return this.element.offsetTop + this.element.clientHeight / 2;
  }

  updateElement() {
    this.element ??= document.getElementById(`box${this.id}`);
  }

  static sortTopDown(firstBox, secondBox) {
    return [firstBox, secondBox].sort((a,b) => a.element.offsetTop - b.element.offsetTop);
  }
}

class Connector {
  constructor(firstBox, secondBox, displayHalf) {
    this.firstBox = firstBox;
    this.secondBox = secondBox;
    this.displayHalf = displayHalf;
    const firstBoxHeight = this.firstBox.getMidpoint();
    this.element = document.createElement("div");
    this.element.classList.add("connector");
    this.element.style.top = firstBoxHeight + "px";
    let secondBoxHeight;
    if (this.displayHalf) {
      secondBoxHeight = this.firstBox.element.parentElement.clientHeight;
      this.element.style.borderBottom = "unset";
    } else {
      secondBoxHeight = this.secondBox.getMidpoint();
    }
    this.element.style.height = Math.abs(secondBoxHeight - firstBoxHeight) + "px";
  }
}

const connectButton = document.getElementById("connect");
const error = document.getElementById("error");
const addBoxButton = document.getElementById("addBox");
const container = new Container(document.getElementById("container"));

connectButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const firstBoxId = document.getElementById("selectFirstBox").value;
  const secondBoxId = document.getElementById("selectSecondBox").value;
  if (firstBoxId === "" || secondBoxId === "") return;
  error.style.display = firstBoxId === secondBoxId ? "block" : "none";
  const firstBox = new Box(firstBoxId);
  const secondBox = new Box(secondBoxId);
  // Check for undrawn cards  
  if (!!firstBox.element ^ !!secondBox.element) {
    return container.addConnector(firstBox, secondBox, true);
  }
  const [topBox, bottomBox] = Box.sortTopDown(firstBox, secondBox);  
  container.addConnector(topBox, bottomBox);
});

window.addEventListener("resize", () => container.checkConnectors());

addBoxButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const box = document.createElement("div");
  box.innerText = 5;
  box.id = "box5";
  box.classList.add("box");
  container.element.appendChild(box);
  addBoxButton.style.display = 'none';  
  container.checkConnectors();
});
```

```css
.box {
  border: solid 1px;
  width: 60px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

#inputs {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

#inputs input {
  width: 150px;
}

.connector {
  position: absolute;
  border-top: solid 1px;
  border-left: solid 1px;
  border-bottom: solid 1px;
  width: 29px;
}

#error {
  display: none;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="box1" class="box">1</div>
  <div id="box2" class="box">2</div>
  <div id="box3" class="box">3</div>
  <div id="box4" class="box">4</div>
</div>
<div id="inputs">
  <input id="selectFirstBox" type="number" placeholder="Provide first box id" min="1" value="1" max="5" />
  <input id="selectSecondBox" type="number" placeholder="Provide second box id" min="1" value="5" max="5" />
  <div id="error">Please select different boxes to connect.</div>
</div>
<button id="connect">Connect</button>
<button id="addBox">Add box 5</button>
```

Comment: Works a charm. Really I was only looking for guidance as to which approach was best.  You coded a whole solution that I can play with so thanks for that.

Comment: @RossDrew It grew a bit over time that's for sure haha. Anyways, happy to help.